# frame does not appear in xelatex

Tags: xetex, titlesec, polyglossia, arabic, frame-title

I'm new in Xelatex, I'm trying to write a text with arabic font so I used polyglossia package and everything is okay but when I worked with titlesec the frame is not appearing if I used arbic or english font, please help me

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=3.5cm,vmargin=5cm}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[frame]
{\normalsize}
{\filright\rmfamily\Large
\enspace Chapitre \thechapter\enspace}
{18pt}
{\rmfamily\huge\bfseries\filcenter}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.65]{Traditional Arabic}



\begin{document}


\chapter*{\begin{Arabic} الملخص \end{Arabic}}
end{document}
```

I want a result like thise but with arabic title
[image]

but when I compile with xelatex and used polyglossia I had this result without frame
[image]

I want the title in arabic in frame

Comment: Do you have both starred and unstarred chapters? How do you want them treated differently? Does using the same code with simply `\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]...` do what you want?

Comment: You might also need to move the `\titleformat` command until right before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @frabjous I used the same code with pdflatex and I had the result in image (with introduction) but with polyglossia I can't use pdflatex so I use xelatex, for example if I use titleformat{\chapter}[frame] and I do \chapter{intro} I will not have a frame like the image

Comment: as @frabjous wrote: move the titleformat definition behind the language selection. arabic loads bidi and that redefines lots of things and so your changes are lost.

Comment: I tried this but I don't have a frame like in picture, I don't have any frame

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I edit my post for more the detail

Comment: If I use your code, and (1) move the `\titleformat` command to right before `\begin{document}`, (2) change `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}` to `\titleformat{\chapter}`, (3) change `end{document}` to `\end{document}` (I assume that was just a typo), and run with xelatex, I get this result: [imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/9ssnCBS). Isn't that what you want? Or do you get a different result?

Comment: thanks a lot @frabjous that's what I want exactly thank you again